# Countifs statement compiles but fails with runtime error 438

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that builds charts on one sheet from data in other sheets in the same book. Currently, it compiles but stops on a countifs statement that looks at dates on one of the other sheets.

The offending line is:

```
thisBook.rSheet.Range(i, "T") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
thisBook.sSheet.Cells("K2", "K" & sSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row), "APPROVED", _
thisBook.sSheet.Cells("M2", "M" & sSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), ">=" & (rSheet.Range(i, "S").Value2 - 6), _
thisBook.sSheet.Cells("M2", "M" & sSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), "<=" & (rSheet.Range(i, "S").Value2))
```

The statement is intended to count rows on another sheet where the text in column K equals "APPROVED" and has a date in column M within a specific week . i loops through the 8 rows of this table. Column S is the date that week ends.

Everything has been fully referenced to avoid

> runtime error 1004

thisBook is the workbook, rSheet is the sheet with the charts, sSheet is the sheet with the table to evaluate.

Which object doesn't support the property or method here?

Comment: I believe you want `.Range()`, instead of `.Cells()` in the first part: `thisBook.sSheet.Range("K2", ...`.  You can't do, say, `Cells("A1","A10")`, instead you want `Range("A1","A10")`.

Comment: @BruceWayne I've tried both, same error.

Comment: @BruceWayne Also, changing all instances of .Cells to .Range gives a runtime error 1004.

Comment: Have you included `Option Explicit` at the top of the module?  And @BruceWayne is correct - you need to use Range() here

Comment: If rSheet and sSheet are already assigned then you don't need (eg) `thisBook.rSheet` - just use `rSheet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, slightly tweaked to make it easier (I hope) to read/follow:

```
Dim outputRng As Range
Dim rSheetVal as Date 
Set outputRng = rsheet.Range(i, "T")
rSheetVal = rsheet.Cells(i, "S").Value2   ' OR, rsheet.Range("S"&i).Value2

With thisBook.sSheet
    outputRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
                .Range("K2", "K" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row), "APPROVED", _
                .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), ">=" & (rSheetVal-6), _
                .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), "<=" & (rSheetVal))
End With
```

Assuming the `thisBook` and `rsheet` are set like:

```
Set thisBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set rSheet = thisBook.Sheets("r Sheet")
```

Comment: Testing this, getting a runtime 1004 on " rSheetVal = rsheet.Range(i, "S").Value2  ". The value of that cell is " 1/14/2018 "

Comment: @SamBasso - D'oh! That should be `.... = rsheet.Cells(i,"S").Value2` I'll edit my post.  Also, I think it'd work better with `Dim rSheetVal as Date`, not `Long`. If `Date` isn't working try `as String`.

Comment: That worked for the outputRng and rSheetVal lines. But now I get the runtime 438 on " With thisBook.sSheet " and I don't know whats even real anymore.

Comment: @SamBasso - Hahhaha...Since I don't know how you declared `sSheet`, maybe you just need `With sSheet`? (Assuming you did `Dim sSheet as Worksheet // Set sSheet = thisBook.Sheets("whatever")`?  If you can edit your OP to include how you declared all the variables, it would help.

Comment: With sSheet did it. Don't know why, but its going now, only problem is that the statement fails to count anything and I get a table full of 0s. Thats probably another question.